# custom module to create multiple forms with pop-ups

Tags: forms, chaos-tool-suite

I am working on a custom module to create a form. Functionality of the module is as follows: The first form has an url, on clicking the url it should show another form as a pop-up. 
How can i call these forms in the hook menu.
Does tools_js has any significance?

```
<?php

function patient_menu() {


$items['patient_add/mainpage'] = array(
    'title' => 'New Patient',
    'page callback' => 'patient_form',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
//a link to add patient diseases

$items['patient_add/%ctools_js'] = array(
'page callback' => 'patient_callback',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

return $items;
}

 // a function to make a  link
function _patient_make_link($link_text = '') {

 return '<div id="patient">' . l($link_text, 'patient_add/nojs', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'ctools-use-modal'))) . '</div>';
}
//first form

function patient_form($form, &$form_state)  {
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();    

$form['p_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'), 
    '#size' => 30, 
    '#maxlength' => 128, 
    '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['age'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Age'), 
    '#size' => 30, 
    '#maxlength' => 30, 
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t( 'in Years' )),
);


$form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => t('Add Patient'),
    '#type' => 'submit',
);

_patient_make_link('add disease details');

return $form;

}

//Ajax menu callback

function patient_callback($ajax) {
if ($ajax) {
ctools_include('ajax');
ctools_include('modal');

$form_state = array(
  'ajax' => TRUE,
  'title' => t('disease details'),
);
$output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('disease_form', $form_state);
if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
  $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
}
print ajax_render($output);
drupal_exit();
}
 else {
  return drupal_get_form('disease_form');
  }
}
//second form
function disease_form($form, $form_state){
  $form['disease_ids'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Disease IDs'),
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#options' => array(
        'Cancer' => 'Cancer',
        'Dengu' => 'Dengu',
        'Viral Fever' => 'Viral Fever',
        'Malaria' => 'Malaria',
    ), 
);
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Submit'),
);
return $form;

}


function patient_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are partial on the right path, I would suggest following a guide like https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/insert-form-pop-modal-ctools-and-drupal-7 and then work your way towards what you need based on that.

Comment: I am working with two forms. In the above example they are working with only one form.